# How to Set Flag =0 when Flag=1 on both CTEs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two CTEs, ATQPreschool_CTE and ANS_CTE. Based on the IndividualID from the two CTEs, The Flag Count = 1 if A1.PreschoolSum > A2.PreschoolSum and A1.ANS_ArrSum > A2.ANS_DepSum. Does anyone know how I can combine the two CTEs and change the Flag = 0 when The ATQPreschool_CTE and ANS_CTE both have a Flag = 1 for the Individual? So after the two CTE's have been combining something like:

```
case when ATQPreschool_CTE.Flag = 1 and ANS_CTE.Flag = 1 and ATQInfant_IndividualID = ANS_IndividualID then Flag = 0 else 1 end as UpdatedFlag
```

These are my two CTEs:

```
    WITH ATQPreschool_CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ATQPreschool_IndividualID ORDER BY ATQPreschool_CreateDate) AS rownum
        FROM 
            [dbo].[vCDCP_rptPreschoolImprove]
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A1.ATQPreschool_IndividualID,
        A1.ATQPreschool_CreateDate,
        A1.PreschoolSum as PreschoolName_A1,
        A2.PreschoolSum As PreschoolName_A2,
        CASE 
           WHEN 
A1.PreschoolSum > A2.PreschoolSum and
not exists(select 1 from ATQPreschool_CTE A3 where A1.ATQPreschool_IndividualID = A3.ATQPreschool_IndividualID and A1.ATQPreschool_CreateDate < A3.ATQPreschool_CreateDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS flag
    FROM
        ATQPreschool_CTE AS A1
    INNER JOIN
        ATQPreschool_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ATQPreschool_IndividualID = A2.ATQPreschool_IndividualID 
                            AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1
```

2nd CTE:

```
    WITH ANS_CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ANS_IndividualID ORDER BY ANS_SubmitDate) AS rownum
        FROM 
            [dbo].[vCDCP_rptANSImprove]
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A1.ANS_IndividualID,
        A1.ANS_SubmitDate,
        A1.ANS_ArrSum,
        A2.ANS_DepSum,
        CASE 
           WHEN 
A1.ANS_ArrSum > A2.ANS_DepSum and
not exists(select 1 from ANS_CTE A3 where A1.ANS_IndividualID = A3.ANS_IndividualID and A1.ANS_SubmitDate < A3.ANS_SubmitDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS flag
    FROM
        ANS_CTE AS A1
    INNER JOIN
        ANS_CTE AS A2 ON A1.ANS_IndividualID = A2.ANS_IndividualID 
                            AND A1.rownum = A2.rownum + 1
```

Comment: You mean you want to jsut access both CTEs to get the results from each and do something with it? Just place your second CTE underneath the first one, separate them with a comma(,) and remove the WITH on the second CTE, now you can write a script below that which can use both CTEs data. Like this: https://stevestedman.com/2011/12/multiple-ctes-in-a-single-query/

Comment: I've tried to put a comma and remove the WITH for the second CTE, but get an error "Incorrect syntax near ','."

Comment: You have to put the 2nd CTE immediately after the first. Then you can query them both, but only with one query. After the first select is executed, you can't refer to the cte's again.